# Cannot resolve native module in package when building Angular CLI project

Tags: node.js, angular, electron

**Background**

I'm creating an application that allows users to interact with basic web controls which output controller events through emulated virtual controllers (so user slides a slider, and that manifests in the system as an axis being changed on a virtual controller). I'm building this as an Electron app which contains an Angular CLI project.

To get the virtual controller functionality I'm consuming a project which wraps native virtual controller functionality and exposes it for node applications. ([node-ViGEmClient](https://github.com/jangxx/node-ViGEmClient))

**Issue**

I've created the basic project and imported the required package. However, when I build the project with ng-build I get the following errors:

*./node_modules/vigemclient/lib/DS4Controller.js:1:20-59 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../build/Release/vigemclient' in 'C:\Develop\WebDev\Node\deskpad\node_modules\vigemclient\lib'*

Tracking these errors down, they come from files like this:

[image]

Looking further into the package's structure, it should be looking for vigemclient.node in build/Release, and that file is indeed present:

[image]

I feel like there is some configuration I need to do in Angular (something to do with webpack?) but I don't know what it is. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

In case anyone wants to poke around with my (currently barebones) project, it's located here: [DeskPad](https://github.com/Exaxis/DeskPad)

**Project Details**

Node: v16.17.0

Angular CLI: v14.2.3

**REPRODUCING**

1. Create a new Angular CLI project:

   ng new testProj
2. Install ViGEmClient package:

   npm install vigemclient

*Note: This seems to require libraries related to building C++ code which are prompted during the initial install for Node.*

3. Add this line to tsconfig.json to allow synthetic default imports:

   "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
4. Reference the package in the default app component so that it is used:

   import { Component } from '@angular/core';

   import ViGEmClient from 'vigemclient';

   @Component({

   selector: 'app-root',

   templateUrl: './app.component.html',

   styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']

   })

   export class AppComponent {

   title = 'vigTestAngular';

   client = new ViGEmClient();

   }
5. Attempt to build the project with the command "npm run build"

**Outcome:** These errors should be produced:

./node_modules/vigemclient/lib/DS4Controller.js:1:20-59 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../build/Release/vigemclient' in 'C:\Develop\WebDev\Node\vigTestAngular\node_modules\vigemclient\lib'

./node_modules/vigemclient/lib/ViGEmClient.js:1:20-59 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../build/Release/vigemclient' in 'C:\Develop\WebDev\Node\vigTestAngular\node_modules\vigemclient\lib'

./node_modules/vigemclient/lib/ViGEmTarget.js:5:20-59 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../build/Release/vigemclient' in 'C:\Develop\WebDev\Node\vigTestAngular\node_modules\vigemclient\lib'

./node_modules/vigemclient/lib/X360Controller.js:1:20-59 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../build/Release/vigemclient' in 'C:\Develop\WebDev\Node\vigTestAngular\node_modules\vigemclient\lib'

Comment: Note: See [ask] for the reason why it's not preferable to link to off-site (outside-of-stack-overflow) repros.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the exact same error with a native package. In my case this is also an Electron app with angular ~14.2 on Windows.

A friend pointed me to the problem: I was importing the native package from the angular web app code (renderer), but apparently when using native packages in an Electron application, they can only be imported in the Electron main process (main.ts).

Hope this helps!